# Split xml nodes by their distinct attribute value?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<test  volume="1"  />
<test  volume="2"  />
<test  volume="1"  />
<test  volume="3"  />
<test  volume="5"  />
<test  volume="4"  />
<test  volume="4"  />
<test  volume="4"  />
<test  volume="2"  />
```

How can I navigate only through nodes with unique attribute value i.e from 1 to 2 then to 3 and so on. I want to fetch unique values and then wan to split xml file to make a collection of nodes with same attribute values. Is there any other way to make a collection of nodes with distinct attribute value. ie if I make a list for attribute value 4 then list must have 3 nodes. Note here that attribute value is unknown It can be any numerical value. This is just a sample.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use this as your xpath

//test[not(@volume = following::test/@volume)]

this will work for both xpath 1.0 and 2.0

Comment: @VipinMaurya it is simple it will just find the last duplicate value and gets the unique results for example first it will see volume=1 and it children's, has volume one more time so it will be discarded next it will take second volume=1 at position 2 and its children here children's, don't have duplicates so it will fetch that result like that for all elements